# Virus or Windows Update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, virus, anti-virus

## Approach

I am using windows 10 and as always I check the `Services` of my computer. Today reviewing if the `Windows Update` service was running I noticed the following service:

[image: ServiceUnknow]

I thought it was one of the many services that put windows without asking ... So I decided to stop it ...

---

## Problem

> **Service does not stop manually**

But pressing the <kbd>right button</kbd>, I see that **all options are disabled** ...

[image: ServiceBlock]

> **Access denied from `Task Manager`**

I decide to try my luck from `Task Manager`.

I'm looking for the name of the service and  <kbd>Right button</kbd> , `| End task |`:

[image: TaskManagerBlock]

Accept the warning :

[image: Accept Warning]

I get the following windows, **Access denied** :

[image: Access denied]

> **Stop with commands**

I search for information on the Internet and [find something similar](https://superuser.com/questions/1294303/unable-to-end-remove-a-process-i-think-is-a-keylogger-windows-10) and make one of the solutions:

```
sc config "service name" start=demand​
net stop "service name"​
sc config "service name" start=disabled​
```

But when I run it, it fails :

```
> net stop svchost.exe
The service name is not valid.


> net stop svchost.exe
The syntax of this command is:

NET STOP
service
```

> **Antivirus**

I have checked with `Malwarebytes` and `Avast` and have not told me there is a virus but I do not like it and they say it could be a `keylogger`

#### Contradictory information

I have searched for information in two ways :

- Windows 10 Update Facilitation Service

  - [Windows 10 update facilitation service- Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056254/windows-10-update-facilitation-service)
- How `C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k osrss`

  - [Virus](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/startups/OSRSS.exe-12370.html)

---

## Question

**Is it a virus or is it a Windows update?**

Comment: @pimp-juice-it I'm agree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a response in this [Microsoft Answers forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/os-remediation-system-service/671c62b2-705a-44c1-870d-e1ed6555be37), it is a valid Windows service:

> [The] OS Remediation System Service is a [legitimate] service from Microsoft included in [the] KB4056254 update.

The same answer from the same Microsoft Agent provides this [official Microsoft Support link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4056254/windows-10-update-facilitation-service) which gives a few more details:

> This update includes a background service to facilitate Windows Update service on devices running Home or Pro editions of Windows 10 Versions 1507, 1511, 1607, and 1703.
>
> This update includes files and resources to address issues affecting background update processes in the Windows Update servicing stack. Maintaining Window Update service health and performance helps ensure that quality updates are installed seamlessly on your device and help to improve the reliability and security of devices running Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks !!! I thought I would have to format the computer  @anaksunaman

Comment: Your welcome. Reinstalling is never fun. Always nice to avoid it. =P